# TS2740 Type is missing the following properties from ReadOnly<MyInterface> error in React Native with TypeScript app

Tags: typescript, react-native

Since `StatelessComponent` is deprecated, I am trying to turn all the components into classes.

I have an interface, for example:

```
interface MyInterface{
    prop1: number;
    prop2: boolean;
}
```

And I use it in the class:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyInterface> {
   ...
   public render(){...}
}
```

And when I try to use `MyComponent` like this:

```
<MyComponent 
    prop1={3}
    prop2={false}
/>
```

I get this error:

> TS2740: Type {prop1: 3, prop2: false} is missing the following properties from type ReadOnly: render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Seems to work with the code you provided: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-o7jxrp (assuming  `MyComponent ` is `TravelChange` in your jsx tag)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes, it works. But I get that error in the IDE and I would want to make it go away.

Comment: I also get an error with your particular code since `prop2` should be a `string`, but if I correct that it all works and I see no errors in my IDE (or on stackbliz). What IDE are you using ? Maybe restart it ? Maybe you are not importing the same component ?Your code looks fine.

Comment: Yes, I updated the question (now `prop2` is a `boolean`), but I still get the error even after restarting the IDE. I am using WebStorm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by changing the declaration of the class to `class MyComponent extends React.Component<any, MyInterface>`.

Comment: pretty sure this is wrong, the first arg is for Props, second for State

Comment: Yes, you're right @dmo. I can't delete this answer though as it's the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case where I have encountered this error:
Type '{ label: string; value: string; }' is missing the following properties from type ReadOnly is missing the following properties from type length, pop, push, concat, and 15 more.

I had this following code:

```
interface IState {
  currentEnvironment: IEnvironment;
  environmentOptions: IEnvironment[];
}
interface IEnvironment {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}
```

I was initializing the states of array***(In this case environment options)*** as :

```
public state = {
    currentEnvironment: { label: '', value: '' },
    environmentOptions: [],
  };
```

Initializing the state more specifically has resolved issue in my case which goes like:

```
public state = {
    currentEnvironment: { label: '', value: '' },
    environmentOptions: [{ label: '', value: '' }],//Also initializing the properties of the Interface
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue without explicitly typing the class, simply move the `state` out of the `constructor` as shown below:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<any> {
    state = {
        key1: value1,
        key2: value2
    }
    render(){
        return(
           <div>Hello World</div>
        )
    }
}
```

This approach is useful when you have a function that set the state of form inputs like this:

```
handleInputChange = (event)=>{
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
```

So the code below will just fine especially when you are using typescript:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<any> {

      state = {
          key1: value1,
          key2: value2
      }

      handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
          [name]: value // no typing error
        });
      }

      render(){
         return(
            <div>Hello World</div>
         )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For others like me that found this page for other reasons -- I was getting the same typescript error (TS2740) while trying to create an HTML5 canvas like this:

```
this.canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
```

It was creating a canvas fine, but to make the error go away I had to change it to lowercase:

```
this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
```