# What is the proper way to set the PROPS type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm working with REDUX in REACT and am working on getting the mapStateToProps functionality to work correctly.

Here is my component:

```
interface NavProps{
    loggedIn: boolean,
    loggingIn: boolean
}

class Navigator extends Component {

public render(){
    const { loggedIn } = this.props as NavProps;
    return (
        ...removed irrelevant code
      );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootReducer): NavProps => {
    const { authentication } = state;
    const { loggedIn, loggingIn } = authentication;
    return{
        loggedIn,
        loggingIn
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Navigator);
```

Here you can see I used:

```
const { loggedIn } = this.props as NavProps;
```

If not, I get an error that 'loggedIn' is not in this.props.

In the tutorials I looked at, they all used something like this with no problem:

```
const { loggedIn } = this.props
```

Am I doing it correctly or am I missing a step that will make the props correctly reflect what is assigned during mapStateToProps?

Update:
 I've gone back and reviewed a couple of the tutorials on REDUX. I see now they were using JSX, not TSX, so maybe I DO have to use type assertion to appease Typescript.

Update:

A couple of people suggested:

```
class Navigator extends Component <NavProps>
```

However, that produces this error:

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<NavProps, "loggedIn" | "loggingIn">': loggedIn, loggingIn  TS2739

<Router>
22 |       <div className="App">
> 23 |         <Navigator />
```

Not sure if it makes any difference, but here is the component that is embedding NAVIGATOR:

```
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navigator />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/libraries" component={Libraries} />
            </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

Ok, I found a suggestion here:

[TS2740 Type is missing the following properties from ReadOnly error in React Native with TypeScript app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851828/ts2740-type-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-readonlymyinterface-error)

As strange as it seems from the comments below, the answer is to do it like this:

```
class Navigator extends Component<any, any>
```

Even though it doesn't seem right to just stick 'any' in there.

Here is one that is a little clearner:

[TS2739 - Type missing in following properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181194/ts2739-type-missing-in-following-properties)

It suggests making the props optional:

```
interface NavProps{
    loggedIn?: boolean,
    loggingIn?: boolean
}

class Navigator extends Component<NavProps>
```

Comment: how about `class Navigator extends Component<AuthenticationState>`?

Comment: @Andus I believe there are supposed to be 2 assignments, the first for the state and the second for the props. When I made the change you suggested, I got this error: "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<AuthenticationState, "loggedIn" | "loggingIn">': loggedIn, loggingIn"

Comment: I have checked the type of `component` and my guess is the first one is props and the second one is state because it writes: `interface Component<P = {}, S = {}, SS = any>`, I guess `P` is props

Comment: Thanks @Andus. I saw the same thing and was surprised when it only worked the other way around. I made some changes where I am using an interface just for the props. Now I don't even need to use the assignments like that. However, I still have the same issue that I have to use 'this.props as NavProps'

Answer (score 4):

We can see that in [the TypeScript docs here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html#write-some-code):

```
class Navigator extends Component<NavProps> {
```

Here is how it looks on my machine:

[image]

Comment: I get the following error: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<NavProps, "loggedIn" | "loggingIn">': loggedIn, loggingIn  TS2739

    21 |     <Router>
    22 |       <div className="App">
  > 23 |         <Navigator />
       |          ^
    24 |         <Switch>
    25 |           <Route exact path="/libraries" component={Libraries} />
    26 |         </Switch>

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it at all. If I use <NavProps>, I get the error above. If I change it to <{}, NavProps> it does not give me an error, but I still have to use the type assertion.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss I've added an image that might assist you. React is tricky.

Comment: Yeah, tell me about it.

Answer (score 1):

According to my comments above, I have test this and there's no problem at all

```
interface NavProps {
  loggedIn: boolean
  loggingIn: boolean
}

class Navigator extends Component <NavProps> {
  public render() {
    const { loggedIn } = this.props
    console.log(loggedIn)
    return null
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootReducer): NavProps => {
  const { authentication } = state
  const { loggedIn, loggingIn } = authentication
  return {
    loggedIn,
    loggingIn,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Navigator)
```

except that I don't have the `RootReducer` type from your question

---

update: try to write the `connect` like this, too

```
export default connect<NavProps>(mapStateToProps, null)(Navigator)
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<NavProps, "loggedIn" | "loggingIn">': loggedIn, loggingIn  TS2739

    21 |     <Router>
    22 |       <div className="App">
  > 23 |         <Navigator />
       |          ^
    24 |         <Switch>
    25 |           <Route exact path="/libraries" component={Libraries} />
    26 |         </Switch>

Comment: In your comment above, you said to use `AuthenticationState` instead of `NavProps`

Comment: Because the op changed the name of the interface @Jacob

Comment: Oh, sorry didnt notice.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks. Yes, I changed it to an interface in the same file. Not sure why, but doing so removed the need, it seems to add the types at the class name. Plus, it seems better since I might add more items to the props later on that are not part of AuthenticationState.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss sry was in lunch, I'm not sure if it works but you can try my updated part to see if the error still exist

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. I added to my OP a couple of solutions. Neither are pretty because 'any' is involved. But they do resolve the issue of needing to use type assertion and, I believe, led to a better interface pattern than I originally used. Thanks for your responses.